# Can you make constraint that deletes referenced row if reference is set to null in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

We have a postgres table with a foreign key to another table. We need a system, that if the foreign key value is set to NULL, the row it referenced is deleted.

Can it be done using table constraints or do i need to create a trigger for that?

Example:
TABLE P
id: Primary key
child_id: FOregin key(c.id)

Table C
id: PRimary KEy

If P row is deleted, referenced C row must be deleted. If Row in P is updated and the referece is set to NULL the row that was referencedin C must be deleted. If reference in P is set to reference another object. previous reference in C must be deleted.

Comment: Something that can be of help, while it would need customisation is "ON DELETE CASCADE".

check it here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-constraints.html.

i understand that its not the exact use case for you but it can cascade your deletes to the child once done on parent.

Comment: Do you want to delete the referenced (target) row if the row that points at it is deleted? What if there are several rows pointing to the same row? Or do you want dependent rows to vanish if the referenced row is deleted?

Comment: It is ONE-TO-ONE relationship. If the pointing row is deleted, target must be deleted. If pointig row does not point to target, target mus be deleted.

Comment: @MarkoTaht Why not just store the values in the same table then?

Comment: Maybe you could try with two circular deferred foreign key constraints.

Comment: To avoid any misunderstanding please post a kind of https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: @Bergi There is a stupidtly complex system that has to work. nothing i can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that deleting parent row cascades to delete child row (but not sure about the other requirements):

```
create table p(pid int primary key);
CREATE TABLE

create table c(cid int primary key, cfk int references p on delete cascade);
CREATE TABLE

insert into p values(1);
INSERT 0 1

insert into c values(10, 1);
INSERT 0 1

select * from p;
 pid 
-----
   1
(1 row)

select * from c;
 cid | cfk 
-----+-----
  10 |   1
(1 row)

delete from p where pid=1;
DELETE 1

select * from p;
 pid 
-----
(0 rows)

select * from c;
 cid | cfk 
-----+-----
(0 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

> If a row in P is updated and the reference is set to NULL the row that was referenced in C must be deleted.

This is not possible with constraints, this requires a trigger.

However, cross-referential foreign key constraints can do the validation that you require, with

```
ALTER TABLE P ADD FOREIGN KEY (k) REFERENCES C(k) ON DELETE CASCADE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
ALTER TABLE C ADD FOREIGN KEY (k) REFERENCES P(k) ON DELETE CASCADE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

<sup>(See [online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a7bf02d5f618f3190cb6e5dd6b26d256))</sup>